# Prometheus Web API is not enabled

Tags: prometheus

I am running the latest (v2.35.0) docker image of Prometheus and am trying to enable the web admin api. I have tried several variations of this inside of my docker-compose.yml file, but nothing seems to turn it on. Here is the relevant snippet:

```
prometheus:
   container_name: prometheus
   image: "prom/prometheus:latest"
   user: "1000"
   networks:
     - observability
   ports:
     - "9090:9090"
   volumes:
     - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
     - /data/prometheus:/var/lib/prometheus
   command: --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus --web.enable-admin-api
   restart: unless-stopped
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but could use some guidance.

The admin API remains disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
prometheus:
   container_name: prometheus
   image: "prom/prometheus:latest"
   user: "1000"
   networks:
     - observability
   ports:
     - "9090:9090"
   volumes:
     - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
     - /data/prometheus:/var/lib/prometheus
   command:
     - --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
     - --storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus
     - --web.enable-admin-api
   restart: unless-stopped
```

The `command` property takes a YAML list of values.

Each value must be indicated using a hyphen (`- {value}`).

The list values are double-hyphen flags (`--web.enable-admin-api`).

Alternatively, you can use the JSON variant which I've spread over multiple lines but can also be presented as a single line:

```
command: [
  "--config.file=...",
  "--storage.tsdb.path=...",
  "--web.enable-admin-api"
]
```